# Variable issue in ansible JINJA2 template

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I am facing issue in creating JSON file (in JINJA2) by using variables in ansible.

Variables

```
1:    
    abc:
        add1: "1614"
        add2: "1615"
        add3: "1616"
2:    
    deb:
        add5: "1617"
        add6: "1618"
        add7: "1619"
```

In JINJA2 Template, I am defining value like

`value: {{1 | 2}}`

then formatting is not coming correctly. It should come as

```
{
  "abc": {
    "add1": "1614",
    "add2": "1615",
    "add3": "1616"
  },
  "deb": {
    "add5": "1617",
    "add6": "1618",
    "add7": "1619"
  }
}
```

Any suggestion for JINJA2 declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jinja2, the bar character ("`|`") is [used to apply a filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#other-operators), so in this case, it is trying to apply the filter `2`, to `1`, which obviously doesn't make sense!

In this case, I would recommend using Jinja2's [builtin tojson filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#tojson), which will turn a python object into it's closest JSON equivalent. This is present if you are using a version of Jinja2 greater than 2.9.

Ideally I would pre-process the data so that `1` and `2` are in the same dictionary, so you could simply write:

```
{{ combined | tojson }}
```

If this is not an option, you could try the slightly more ugly looking:

```
{{ dict(1, **2) | tojson }}
```

This uses pythons [dict constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) to merge the two dictionaries.

EDIT: If you want to pretty-print your json, call the `tojson` filter with how much of an indent you want, eg. to get 2 space indents use:

```
{{ data | tojson(2) }}
```

Comment: Great! If you're happy with this answer please mark it as correct so that other people can find it too. Thanks!